# Adjust block title height in tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter

I want to reduce the height of block titles on my tikzposter. The tikzposterBlockstyles.tex file doesn't seem to mention an option for doing this, neither does the [documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/tikzposter.pdf/0). Is there a more low level way to achieving this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: MWE:

```
\documentclass[a0paper, landscape, 25pt, colspace=1cm, subcolspace=-1cm, blockverticalspace=1cm]{tikzposter} 
\title{Title}
\author{Person}
\institute{Institute}
%Choose Layout
\usetheme{Default}

\begin{document}
% Title block with title, author, logo, etc.
\maketitle[titletoblockverticalspace=1cm]

\block{Block Title}{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! can you show us a small compilable TeX code you have so far?